# Apply coupon code not working in magento

Tags: api, magento, coupon

I am writing a separate php file outsite Magento to support for our local application.

Apply coupon code part not working for me. But the same coupon works in Magento(userend) and Magento API call too.

I am trying with the same code what Magento have in API.

```
$quoteId = 10001;
$coupon = 'TESTCOUPON';
$storeId = 2;

$quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote");
$quote->setStoreId($storeId);
$quote->load($quoteId);

if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
        echo ('quote_is_empty');
        exit;
}

$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->setCouponCode($coupon)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();

if (!$coupon == $quote->getCouponCode()) {
        echo ('coupon_code_is_not_valid');
        exit;
}
else{
        echo 'coupon applied';
        exit;
}
```

The above code through **coupon_code_is_not_valid**. 
If anyone have any idea for this let me know.

Comment: Do you want to get the coupon code applied when product was ordered?

Comment: yes, after products are added to cart/quote.

Comment: Your code is correct, what issue you are facing?

Comment: when I run the code it through coupon_code_is_not_valid

Comment: compare the stings in case insensitive mode

Comment: I am checked in db too, coupon was not applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
if (strcasecmp($coupon,$quote->getCouponCode()) == 0 ){
    echo 'coupon applied';
     exit;
}
```

Comment: I checked in db too, coupon was not applied.